How to Generate Substrate Keys for a Custom SS58 Format (e.g., 567)?
I am working on a Substrate-based blockchain and need to generate keys for my network, which uses a custom SS58FORMAT = 567. I am using the key subcommand from my Substrate node executable. However, when I try to specify --network 567, I get the following error:
./target/release/node key generate --network 567


error: invalid value '567' for '--network <NETWORK>': Unable to parse variant. Known variants: 
["BareEd25519", "BareSecp256k1", "BareSr25519", "DICO", "ICE", "KICO", "SNOW", "acala", "ajuna", 
...
"zeitgeist", "zero", "zero-alphaville"]

The --network flag only supports predefined network formats and does not directly accept a raw SS58 format.
How can I generate keys for a Substrate chain using a custom SS58 format?
